# Android ProgressBar size take whole screen

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to implement an Android ProgressBar but its size is taking the whole screen. I've followed a couple of examples but it didn't make any effect.

Here is my code

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:padding="45dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Post your code so we know what's the problem is

Comment: post a screenshot...and always post your code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *ProgressBar* is taking the whole screen size, probably because you've set the `layout-width` and/or `layout-height` to `match-parent`.

So try changing those.

Or, if you set the `layout-width` and `layout-height` to *0dp* on a `ConstraintLayout`, then make sure you're not setting the *Constraints* to `parent` on all / opposite sides.

If you're using a `LinearLayout`, and if you've set either the `layout-width` or `layout-height` to *0dp*, then make sure you aren't setting the `layout-weight` to a size that's too different from the `layout-weight` of the other *widgets* of the layout.

Hope this helped. Next time, please post your **code** or even a **screenshot**. That makes it a lot easier for all of us.