# ProgressBar appearing on whole screen in Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to implement ProgressBar in Navigation Drawer Activity but it is covering the whole screen like this.

[image]

I try to set `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"` in my ProgressBar but no success

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_screen"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_screen_drawer" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This question is not duplicate of  [Android ProgressBar size take whole screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128644/android-progressbar-size-take-whole-screen)

Comment: Your layout is incorrect See https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally done

When creating new NavigationDrawer Activity, Android Studio generates 4 XML files. Earlier I was implementing ProgressBar in `activity_home_screen.xml`. Now after trying to implement in `content_home_screen.xml`, it worked

> Note: `HomeScreenActivity` is my Activity name

My `content_home_screen.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".HomeScreenActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home_screen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:weightSum="5">

       <!-- Some Code.... -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_search"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_view" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happened due to hardcoded size of Progress bar

> android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"

Try this:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your ProgressBar inside NavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_screen"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_screen_drawer">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Same idea here, anywhere but in the `DrawerLayout `

Comment: after implementing this Progress bar is not showing on the screen

Comment: it should be shown in the DrawerLayout now @KartikAgarwal. There's no guarantee though, as you're not supposed to do this. It looks like the only option may be to get the header view and add your progress bar programmatically to the header

Comment: yes, now the progressBar is coming in Drawer Header. But I don't want this. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Actually, according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626324/navigationview-and-custom-layout), you should be able to put a custom View inside. Try wrapping the ProgressBar in a LinearLayout.